# To find the row and column position of the cell in the table

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a grid along with an input box. Once I enter the values say 3254 it should get splitted i.e 3,2,5,4.And then it should retrieve the cell position for each of the values.Say for example, the row and column position may be (1,3) for the 1st value 3.After finding the position of the cell i.e  (1,3),it should again get splitted into 1,3. and these values should be assigned to the td tags of the color table correspondingly.The color table gets shuffled each time.
My table:

```
<div class="form-group" >
<div class="col-sm-5">

<table  border="5px" width="500px" height="50px" align="center" id="mytable">
<tr bgcolor="#800000">
<td></td>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>8</td></tr>
<tr >
<td bgcolor="#800000">1</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>1</td><td>7</td> <td>8</td><td>3</td>
<td>2</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>5</td><td>1</td>
<td>6</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">3</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>8</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">4</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>7</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>3</td>
<td>8</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">5</td><td>8</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>   <td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">6</td><td>2</td><td>6</td><td>3</td><td>5</td>   <td>1</td><td>4</td>
<td>8</td><td>7</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">7</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>5</td><td>8</td>   <td>6</td><td>7</td>
<td>2</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#800000">8</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>8</td><td>7</td>
<td>6</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<center>
<input type="text" name="pd" id="pd">
<button id="login">Login</button></center> 
</div></div>
```

HTML code for the color table:

```
<table  border="5px" width="500px" height="50px" align="center">
<tr id="colors">
<label><td  height="50px" ></td></label>
<label><td height="50px" ></td></label>

<label><td height="50px"  ></td></label>
<label><td  height="50px" ></td></label>

<label><td height="50px" ></td></label>
<label><td height="50px" ></td></label>

<label><td height="50px" ></td></label>
<label><td height="50px" ></td></label>

</tr>
</table>
```

Code for splitting using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('#login').click(function() {
var term = $('#pd').val().split('');
alert(term);
 });
```

});

Code for shuffling of colors:

```
var colorCells = document.getElementById('colors').getElementsByTagName('td');
var colors = ["blue","red","green","yellow","orange","pink","brown","black"];
for(var i = 0; i < colorCells.length; i++)
{
    colorCells[i].style.backgroundColor = colors.splice(Math.random() * (colors.length),1);
}
```

Comment: will you please add up a fiddle here!

Comment: _it should again get splitted into 1,3. and these two values should be assigned to the td tag of the table correspondingly_ what do you mean by this? what you are gonna do with those positions?

Comment: Indeed, JSFiddle would be super useful. But also a clearer clarification of what exactly you want to accomplish and what the problem is wouldn't hurt.

Comment: do you wanna highlight columns when the values are entered?

Comment: 3,2,5,4 are elements after the input is split, that I understand, then you say (1,3) is the first value...Where did the 1 come from? What does the 1 represent... column...row? Which one is column and which one is row? So the next value is 2... does another number magically appear like the number 1 did?

Comment: 1,3) is just an example.Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cenrabrk/1/   I want to find the row and column positions  in the grid and assign that row position no for the 1st td tag and assign the column position no to the 2nd td tag in the color table.

Comment: What about multiple values? lets say there are multiple `3`s? what coordinates do you want then?

Comment: That's my problem.I dont know how to do in such a case

Answer (score 0):

The question was not very clear in terms of what exactly wanted after finding the designated cell and what your input should be. Here is an example of any two numbers input in the textbox. Ex. 13. This will then find the cell within the table and apply a css rule to the cell.

If all input should be in pairs I would probably loop over the input ( assuming there is always an even number of items) and then do whatever I had to do during the iteration since I have control over the current row and column.

```
 $('#login').click(function() {
        var term = $('#pd').val().split('');
        console.log(term);
        var $table = $('#mytable').find('tbody');

        var row = parseInt(term[0]) + 1;
        var column = parseInt(term[1]) + 1;

        var $row = $table.find('tr:nth-child(' + row + ')');
        var $cell = $row.find('td:nth-child(' + column + ')');
        $cell.css('background-color', 'green');
        alert(term);

      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cenrabrk/3/

Comment: It's just the opposite .Here you enter the row position and column position and your corresponding cell gets highlighted.But i want my code to enter the cell value and obtain their cell positions.

Comment: What if two cells have the same value?@Preethi

Comment: That's my problem ,I dont know  how to find their specific positions in such a case.